# merging profiles from different branches/orgs

Tags: permissions, profile, merge, git, version-control

would appreciate some suggestions on this problem I'm having.

Essentially it has to do with making a change to a profile, say a field permission and then propagating that through the other environments (by committing to version control and then merge.  The problem I'm seeing is that our profiles in our master branch have diverged quite a bit from our integration branch.  So let's say for example, I branch off master and commit a simple field permission update to the branch.  When I go to merge this change into the integration branch, I get almost 100 conflicts.  Which ok, a merge tool will let me resolve the one conflict and then I can auto accept all the other changes coming from the integration branch (the branch I'm trying to merge into).  Which is what I want because I don't want to lose any of the changes that have been made to the profile in integration.  So I resolve the conflict that my change caused, and merge in all other changes.  The problem I'm seeing is that for the permission I'm trying to merge, the lines don't align well.  In other words, if I merge in my permission change and then accept all changes from integration branch, I will get duplicate permission entries.  What I'm trying to accomplish is an overwrite/replace, but because of the alignment they will both be added and mess up the profile.  This then means I would have to go through all the 100 changes on the integration side.  Which is way tedious and a waste because I don't care what those changes are, I just want to carry them over.  The only way I see it is I have to first start with the integration profiles (get them in a sandbox) make my change there, commit to version control and then the merge to integration branch will go more smoothly because I sourced from integration.

Any ideas on this problem?  Am I going about it the wrong way. Sorry for such a lengthy note, it's a difficult problem to explain.   Thanks!

Comment: I'm not 100% sure wha you're asking but have you looked into these options?

https://sforgcompare.herokuapp.com/
http://www.configworkbook.com/
https://gearset.com/
https://perm-comparator.herokuapp.com/

Answer (score 0):

You aren't going about it the wrong way. It is an issue with how Profiles are currently represented, which may change in the future but is a pain for now.

The approach we take at [gearset](https://gearset.com) is to not treat things like simple XML and instead split the `Foo.profile` into the thousands of constituent components which we then merge back together for you automatically. So you only need to select the field and Gearset will update all the profiles automatically.